# Undefined references to `name' with NVCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to compile the gpgmg CUDA simulation in a non standard way since I do not have root access to the machine I am trying to run it on.

This simulation makes extensive use of the HDF5 library (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). As I am running this on a machine which I do not have root access to I am unable to install HDF5. I therefore downloaded the files and stuck them in an `include` directory. I compile using NVCC with the following command (yes, I know this should be in a makefile format).

```
nvcc main.cpp CAnnihilationProblem.cpp CCompartment.cpp CDiffusionModel.cpp CFirstOrderReaction.cpp CFisherProblem.cpp CLocalizedAnnihilationProblem.cpp CModel.cpp CReaction.cpp CReactionProblem.cpp CSecondOrderReaction.cpp CSemiInfiniteSlabProblem.cpp CSimpleDiffusionProblem.cpp CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem.cpp CSimpleLocalizedFirstOrderReaction.cpp CSimpleLocalizedSecondOrderReaction.cpp CSimpleLocalizedZerothOrderReaction.cpp CZeroOrderReaction.cpp -lgsl -I ../include
```

This compiles fine (if I just use the -c flag), but when I come to link it I get the following errors:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-2_CCompartment.o: In function `gpgmp::CCompartment::saveHdf5(int)':
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `H5open'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `H5open'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CCompartment.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::closeOutputFile(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation const*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x336): undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `H5Fclose'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::prepareOutputFile(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `H5check_version'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `H5Fopen'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x646): undefined reference to `H5Gcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x719): undefined reference to `H5Fclose'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::createOutputFile(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x8f3): undefined reference to `H5check_version'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x923): undefined reference to `H5Fcreate'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x99d): undefined reference to `H5Gcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x9c3): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x9c9): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x9ec): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xa06): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xa0c): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xa2b): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xa36): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xa41): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xad0): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xad6): undefined reference to `H5T_C_S1_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xadb): undefined reference to `H5Tcopy'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xaed): undefined reference to `H5Tset_size'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb03): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb2c): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb5c): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb67): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb8e): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb96): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xb9c): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xbbf): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xbd9): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xbdf): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xbfe): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xc09): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xc14): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xc34): undefined reference to `H5Gcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xcb4): undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xcbf): undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::openOutputFile(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xe1d): undefined reference to `H5check_version'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xe48): undefined reference to `H5Fopen'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0xf9c): undefined reference to `H5Gopen2'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::writeAllSpecies(float, gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x141b): undefined reference to `H5Gcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x147f): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1487): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x148d): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14b0): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14b8): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14be): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14e0): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14eb): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x14f6): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x15c6): undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x15ce): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x15d4): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x161e): undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x165e): undefined reference to `H5open'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1664): undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1683): undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x168e): undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1699): undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x16bb): undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::runSomeGmps(void*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x17ff): undefined reference to `chooseDevice(int)'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1883): undefined reference to `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::cudaRunGMPInhomogeneous(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)'
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x1892): undefined reference to `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::cudaRunGMP(gpgmp::DiffusionModelRuntimeInformation*)'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-3_CDiffusionModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CDiffusionModel::runMultipleGmps(int, int, float, float, float, int, bool, void*)':
CDiffusionModel.cpp:(.text+0x2b4d): undefined reference to `queryCudaDevices()'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000061e_00000000-7_CModel.o: In function `gpgmp::CModel::gillespie(int, bool)':
CModel.cpp:(.text+0x8d9): undefined reference to `gpgmp::cudaRunGillespie(float*, int*, float*, float*, gpgmp::RateLaw*, int, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My first thought was that `main()` was not defined, but it is. Here's main.cpp:

```
#include "CModel.h"
#include "CDiffusionModel.h"
#include "CAnnihilationProblem.h"
#include "CSemiInfiniteSlabProblem.h"
#include "CSimpleDiffusionProblem.h"
#include "CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem.h"
#include "CLocalizedAnnihilationProblem.h"
#include "CFisherProblem.h"
#include "CReactionProblem.h"
#include "definitions.h"
#include "CSecondOrderReaction.h"

#include <getopt.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int chooseCudaDevice(int device);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // parameters
    int dx=32, dy=32;
    int numRuns=10;
    int numSteps=500000;
    float time=100.;
    REAL length=40.;

    //opterr = 0;
    int c;

    int numCudaDevices=-1;
    int problem=0;
    float p0 = 0.1;
    float dt = 0.1;

    gpgmp::OutputFormat outputFormat = gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5;

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "x:y:t:l:n:r:d:p:w:o:f:")) != -1)
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'x':
            dx = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'y':
            dy = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 't':
            time = atof(optarg);
            break;
        case 'l':
            length = atof(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            numSteps = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'r':
            numRuns = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            // number of devices to run on
            numCudaDevices = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'p':
            problem = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            dt = atof(optarg);
            break;
        case 'w':
            p0 = atof(optarg);
            break;
        case 'f':
            switch(atoi(optarg)) {
            case 0:
                cout <<"Setting output format to ASCII.\n";
                outputFormat = gpgmp::OUTPUT_ASCII;
                break;
            case 1:
                cout <<"Setting output format to HDF5.\n";
                outputFormat = gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5;
                break;
            }
            break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'x' || optopt =='y' || optopt == 't'
                        || optopt =='l' || optopt == 'n' || optopt=='r' || optopt=='d'
                                || optopt=='p' || optopt == 'w')
                    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf (stderr,
                            "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                            optopt);
                return 1;
            default:
                abort ();
        }


    int index=optind;

    cout <<"Welcome to gmp.\n";
    cout <<"System dimensions: length="<<length
            <<", dx="<<dx<<", dy="<<dy<<"\n";
    cout <<"Runtime configuration: time="<<time
            <<", number of Runs="<<numRuns
            <<", number of Steps="<<numSteps
            <<", output dt="<<dt
            <<", problem nr="<<problem
            <<"\n";


    if (problem == 0) {
        // A plus B reaction model
        float diffusionConstant;
        float k1;
        float k2;
        float k3;
        float k4;
        if (index == argc-5) {
            diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
            k1=atof(argv[index++]);
            k2=atof(argv[index++]);
            k3=atof(argv[index++]);
            k4=atof(argv[index++]);
        } else if (index==argc) {
            cout <<"No parameters given, using default.\n";
            length=100.;
            dx=128;
            dy=128;
            p0=0.1;
            time=500.;
            k1=1e-3;
            k2=1e-2;
            k3=1.2;
            k4=1.;
            diffusionConstant=0.;
        } else {
            cout <<"Mismatching parameters. Usage:\n";
            cout <<"gpgmp -p 3 [diffusionConstant k1 k2 k3 k4].\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        cout <<"Setting up A plus B reaction problem with diffusion Constant :"
                <<diffusionConstant<<"\n";
        cout <<"k1 = "<<k1<<", k2 = "<<k2<<", k3 = "<<k3<<", k4 = "<<k4<<"\n";
        gpgmp::CReactionProblem reaction(length, dx, dy, diffusionConstant, k1, k2, k3, k4);
        reaction.setOutputFormat(outputFormat);
        reaction.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt);
    } else if (problem == 1) {
        // FISHER PROBLEM
        float baseConcentration = atof(argv[index++]);
        cout <<"Setting up Fisher Problem with concentration "<<baseConcentration<<".\n";

        gpgmp::CFisherProblem fisher(length, dx, dy, baseConcentration);
        fisher.setOutputFormat(gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5);
        fisher.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt);
    } else if (problem == 2) {
        // SIMPLE DIFFUSION
        float diffusionConstant;
        int numMolecules;

        if (index == argc-2) {
            diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
            numMolecules = atoi(argv[index++]);
        } else if (index==argc) {
            cout <<"No parameters given, using default.\n";
            length=100.;
            dx=128;
            dy=128;
            p0=0.1;
            dt = 5.;
            time=20.;
            diffusionConstant=1.;
            numMolecules = 1e5;
        } else {
            cout <<"Mismatching parameters. Usage:\n";
            cout <<"gpgmp -p 2 [diffusionConstant numMolecules].\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        cout <<"Setting up simple diffusion problem with diffusion Constant :"<<diffusionConstant
                <<", nMol:"<<numMolecules<<" \n";

        gpgmp::CSimpleDiffusionProblem diffusion(
                length, dx, dy, diffusionConstant, numMolecules);
        diffusion.setOutputFormat(gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5);
        diffusion.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt,numCudaDevices);
    } else if (problem ==3) {
        // LOCALIZED A+B ANNIHILATION
        cout <<"Setting up localized A plus B reaction problem.\n";
        float diffusionConstant;
        float k1, k2, k3, k4;
        float xminA, xmaxA,xminB, xmaxB;

        if (index == argc-9) {
            diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
            k1=atof(argv[index++]);
            k2=atof(argv[index++]);
            k3=atof(argv[index++]);
            k4=atof(argv[index++]);
            xminA=atof(argv[index++]);
            xmaxA=atof(argv[index++]);
            xminB=atof(argv[index++]);
            xmaxB=atof(argv[index++]);
        } else if (index==argc) {
            cout <<"No parameters given, using default.\n";
            length=1000.;
            dx=32;
            dy=32;
            p0=0.1;
            time=1800.;
            k1=9.4096e+09;
            k2=9.4096e+10;
            k3=1.27529e-13;
            k4=1.06274e-13;
            diffusionConstant=100.;
            xminA = 0.;
            xmaxA = 900.;
            xminB = 400.;
            xmaxB = 1000.;
        } else {
            cout <<"Mismatching parameters. Usage:\n";
            cout <<"gpgmp -p 3 [diffusionConstant k1 k2 k3 k4 xminA xmaxA xminB xmaxB].\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        cout <<"Parameters : diffusion Constant :"<<diffusionConstant<<"\n";
        cout <<"k1 = "<<k1<<", k2 = "<<k2<<", k3 = "<<k3<<", k4 = "<<k4<<"\n";
        cout <<"xminA = "<<xminA<<", xmaxA = "<<xmaxA<<", xminB = "<<xminB<<", xmaxB = "<<xmaxB<<"\n";

        gpgmp::CLocalizedAnnihilationProblem problem(length, dx, dy,
                diffusionConstant, k1, k2, k3, k4,
                xminA, xmaxA, xminB, xmaxB);
        problem.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt);
    } else if (problem == 4) {
        // SEMI-INFINITE SLAB problem
        cout <<"Setting up semi-infinite slab problem.\n";
        float diffusionConstant;
        float sourceNumber;

        if (index == argc-2) {
            diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
            sourceNumber=atof(argv[index++]);
        } else if (index==argc) {
            cout <<"No parameters given, using default.\n";
            length=40.;
            dx=64;
            dy=64;
            p0=0.1;
            time=1000;
            diffusionConstant=1.;
            sourceNumber = 10.;
            dt=500.;
        } else {
            cout <<"Mismatching parameters. Usage:\n";
            cout <<"gpgmp -p 4 [diffusionConstant sourceNumber].\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        cout <<"Setting up semi-infinite slab problem.\n";
        cout <<"Source number is:"<<sourceNumber<<", diffusion Constant:"
                <<diffusionConstant<<"\n";
        gpgmp::CSemiInfiniteSlabProblem
        slabModel(length, dx, dy, sourceNumber, diffusionConstant);
        slabModel.setOutputFormat(gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5);
        slabModel.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt);
    } else if (problem == 5) {
        // Sets up the A+B annihilation model
        REAL length = 12.8; // In micrometer
        REAL nx = 64; // Number of cells in each direction
        gpgmp::CDiffusionModel testModel(length, nx, nx);

        // add species to model
        REAL diffusivity = 1; // In micrometer^2 s^-1
        testModel.addDiffusionSpecies("A", diffusivity);
        testModel.addDiffusionSpecies("B", diffusivity);
        testModel.addDiffusionSpecies("C", diffusivity);


        // create "source" and "world" compartments
        gpgmp::CCompartment comp1("Source", 32, 32, 32, 32);
        gpgmp::CCompartment comp2("World",0, 0, 63, 63);

        // add species to compartment
        comp1.setInitialAmount("A", 1000, gpgmp::DIST_HOMOGENEOUS);
        comp2.setInitialAmount("B", 1000, gpgmp::DIST_RANDOM);

        // and add it to the main model
        testModel.addCompartment(0, comp1);
        testModel.addCompartment(1, comp2);

        // add the annihilation reaction
        // A+B -> C
        REAL reactionRate = 1e8; // Reaction rate in M^-1 s^-1

        // set the reaction products
        std::map<std::string, int> aplusbAnnihilationMap;
        aplusbAnnihilationMap["C"]=1;

        // and create the reaction
        gpgmp::CSecondOrderReaction *aplusbAnnihilation =
                new gpgmp::CSecondOrderReaction("A plus B annihilation",
                testModel.getSecondOrderReactionRate(reactionRate),
                "A", "B", aplusbAnnihilationMap);
        testModel.addReaction(aplusbAnnihilation);

        // set output format
        testModel.setOutputFormat(gpgmp::OUTPUT_HDF5);

        // run the GMP to test the output
        int nRuns = 100; // Number of runs
        int nSteps = 10000; // Max number of steps
        REAL simTime = 5.; // Max simulation time
        REAL p = 0.1; // Probability for a particle to stay
        REAL dumpTime = 1.; // Interval of output dumps
        testModel.runMultipleGmps(nRuns, nSteps, simTime, p, dumpTime);

    } else if (problem==6) {
        // 2D A+B annihilation problem
        std::cout <<"Setting up 2D annihilation problem.";

        // default parameters
        REAL diffusionConstant = 1.;
        REAL rate;
        int numMolecules;

        // check if more parameters are given - if not take defaults
        if (index == argc-3) {
            diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
            rate=atof(argv[index++]);
            numMolecules = atoi(argv[index++]);
        } else if (index == argc) {
            // use defaults
            cout <<"No parameters given ... using defaults.\n";
            length=12.8;
            dx=64;
            dy=64;
            p0=0.1;
            time=4.;
            rate = 1e8;
            numMolecules = 100000.;
        } else {
            cout <<"Mismatching parameters. Usage:\n";
            cout <<"gpgmp -p 6 diffusionConstant rate numMolecules.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        std::cout <<"Annihilation rate is:"<<rate<<", diffusion Constant:"
                <<diffusionConstant<<", number of Molecules:"
                <<numMolecules<<".\n";

        gpgmp::CAnnihilationProblem model(length, dx, dy, numMolecules,
                diffusionConstant, rate);
        model.setOutputFormat(outputFormat);
        model.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt,numCudaDevices);
    } else if (problem == 7) {
        // SIMPLE INHOMOGENEOUS DIFFUSION
        float diffusionConstant=atof(argv[index++]);
        int numMolecules = atoi(argv[index++]);
        int testModel = atoi(argv[index++]);

        gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters kernelParams;

        // set dimensionality
        kernelParams.dimensionality = 1;

        cout <<"Setting up simple inhomogeneous diffusion problem with diffusion Constant :"
                <<diffusionConstant <<", nMol:"<<numMolecules<<".\n";
        cout <<"Test model is ";
        REAL u0, a;

        gpgmp::CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem *diffusion;

        switch (testModel) {
        case 0:
            cout <<"constant diffusivity.\n";
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_HOMOGENEOUS;
            diffusion = new gpgmp::CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem(
                    length, dx, dy, diffusionConstant, numMolecules, true);
            break;
        case 1:
            u0 = atof(argv[index++]);
            cout <<"population pressure model with u0="<<u0<<".\n";
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_LOCAL_AVERAGE;
            kernelParams.testModelType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::TM_POPULATION_PRESSURE;
            kernelParams.u0 = u0;
            diffusion = new gpgmp::CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem(
                    length, dx, dy, diffusionConstant, numMolecules, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            a = atof(argv[index++]);
            cout <<"contact inhibition model with A="<<a<<".\n";
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_LOCAL_AVERAGE;
            kernelParams.testModelType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::TM_CONTACT_INHIBITION;
            kernelParams.a = a;
            diffusion = new gpgmp::CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem(
                    length, dx, dy, diffusionConstant, numMolecules, false);
            break;
        }

        diffusion->runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt,numCudaDevices,
                true, (void *) &kernelParams);
    } else if (problem == 8) {
        // Slit Problem
        REAL length = 1200.;
        gpgmp::CDiffusionModel testModel(length, dx, dy);

        // create new Compartment
        gpgmp::CCompartment comp1("Explant", dx/2-1, dy/2-1, dx/2, dy/2);

        // add species to compartment
        comp1.setInitialAmount("Cells", 20398, gpgmp::DIST_HOMOGENEOUS);

        // and add it to the main model
        testModel.addCompartment(0, comp1);

        // add species
        testModel.addDiffusionSpecies("Cells", 0.56);

        // create the kernel parameters structure
        gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters kernelParams;
        kernelParams.dimensionality = 2;
        kernelParams.testModelType =
                gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::TM_SLIT;
        // slit parameters
        kernelParams.lambda = 0.01;
        kernelParams.beta = 20;
        kernelParams.length = length;
        REAL subVolume = length/dx*length/dx;
        kernelParams.a = 0.02*subVolume;
        kernelParams.ta = 24.*3600.;
        kernelParams.xi = 1e4/3600.;

        // set diffusion type
        int diffType = atoi(argv[index++]);

        switch(diffType) {
        case 0:
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_STRICTLY_LOCAL;
            break;
        case 1:
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_LOCAL_AVERAGE;
            break;
        case 2:
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_NEIGHBOUR_BASED;
            break;
        case 3:
            kernelParams.diffusionType =
                    gpgmp::InhomogeneousDiffusionParameters::DT_GRADIENT_BASED;
            break;
        }

        // run the GMP to test the output
        testModel.runMultipleGmps(numRuns, numSteps, time, p0, dt, numCudaDevices,
                true, (void *) &kernelParams);
    }
}
```

As this is peer reviewed code, I am assuming the error is with the way I am linking it....

How can I get it to link properly?

Comment: Maybe your command line should include "main.cpp"?

Comment: also seems like you will need to point the linker to whereever the hdf5 libraries are on your system (either on the system or wherever you put them locally) e.g. -L/opt/hdf/lib -lhdf5    or something like that.

Comment: I still get the same errors - I'll edit the question though

Comment: @RobertCrovella I thought that was taken care of by -I ../include.
In addition it is not installed in a traditional sense, there are just a bunch of .h files in above directory (not .so or .a files etc)

Comment: How are you compiling this? If you are using the command line, the `-I` flag indicates where include files are. You also need to specify what libraries are needed using the `-l` flag.

Comment: @RRs_Ghost no it is not taken care of by the -I switch.  You will need .so (dynamic) or .a (static) libraries for hdf5 to link against, somewhere on your system.  A bunch of .h files is not enough as you have discovered.  That will get you through the compile step but not the link step.

Comment: @RobertCrovella and Code-Guru: What is the difference between between the includes and the .so or .a files then? This is the first time I have developed for Linux... Can I build the .so / .a files from the source? Why does one need both?

Comment: Suppose I have a statically linked library (which is what a .a file is).  The headers (.h) define the API (function names) but do not specify a function entry point (i.e. a logical address for the jump commands).  The linker takes the library, identifies the addresses of function entry points, and updates your code with actual jump addresses instead of the place holders created by the compiler.  Conceptually this is no different between windows and linux development, for statically linked libraries.  A similar statement can be made about .so (linux) and .dll (windows) dynamic libraries.

Comment: You probably don't need both .so and .a but it will depend on how your app is set up.  You can probably build the .so or .a files from source, you'll need to investigate the hdf5 library for more info on this.  It may also be possible to install a pre-built set of libraries, [appropriate to your particular linux distro](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html).

Answer (score 1):

You must *explicitly* link library dependencies in your code. The error here is caused by not linking a suitable HDF5 library, leading to unsatisfied dependencies. If you have the missing libraries installed in a path `../include` relative to the working directory then something like this:

```
nvcc -I ../include main.cpp CAnnihilationProblem.cpp CCompartment.cpp CDiffusionModel.cpp \
      CFirstOrderReaction.cpp CFisherProblem.cpp CLocalizedAnnihilationProblem.cpp \ 
      CModel.cpp CReaction.cpp CReactionProblem.cpp CSecondOrderReaction.cpp 
      CSemiInfiniteSlabProblem.cpp CSimpleDiffusionProblem.cpp \
      CSimpleInhomogeneousDiffusionProblem.cpp \
      CSimpleLocalizedFirstOrderReaction.cpp CSimpleLocalizedSecondOrderReaction.cpp  \
      CSimpleLocalizedZerothOrderReaction.cpp CZeroOrderReaction.cpp \
      -L../include -lgsl -lhdf5
```

*should* allow the code to link correctly.

[This answer assembled from comments as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered list].